# Is there a way to link function to button in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I would like to create a button to download the data contained in the table of my HTML page. First of all I thought of saving the data in a table in my database and then create a function that can be called up when the button is clicked (I specify that I would not want to be directed to any page and therefore to remain in the same where the button is). How can I link this function to the button? I tried using onClick() but it doesn't work.

This is the HTML code

```
<form method="GET" align="center" >
        <button onclick="download_file()" id="download-button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg active" type="submit">Download Table</button>
    </form>
```

Thanks to everyone

Comment: Is `download_file()` a defined JavaScript function?

Comment: @OlvinRoght No, it's function in my Python code

Comment: You can't call python function from HTML directly, you can define another route which will be served using this function and set it's path in form `action`.

Comment: By defining another route, can I stay on the same page (i.e. with the same URL)?

Comment: You can create an endpoint that serves the file, for example with [`send_file`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/api/#flask.send_file). The call can then be made with an anchor. Setting the [`download`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download) parameter does not redirect to another page. The file will be downloaded.

Comment: @Detlef Thank you for your answer. I solved creating a function in js

Comment: @Lucus. You need to show the correct answer for everyone else to see the response. It helps a multitude of other users. In fact, you can even answer your own question.